# Next future date not picked from rota schedule correctly

Tags: javascript

I have a bit of an issue with this block of code.

It is meant to find the next rota schedule in an array, ignoring any previous ones.

However if the today's date is 2022-03-09, it picks up 2022-03-08T13:00:00.000Z as the next possible future date. I think this is wrong. It should return 2023-04-13T13:00:00.000Z.

How can I fix this?

```
export const rotaSchedules = [
  '2021-12-13T12:00:00.000Z',
  '2021-12-13T14:00:00.000Z',
  '2022-01-13T14:00:00.000Z',
  '2022-01-23T14:00:00.000Z',
  '2022-01-24T13:00:00.000Z',
  '2022-02-12T17:02:33.000Z',
  '2022-02-12T17:03:59.000Z',
  '2022-02-12T17:36:18.000Z',
  '2022-02-12T17:36:48.000Z',
  '2022-02-12T17:37:22.000Z',
  '2022-02-12T17:37:45.000Z',
  '2022-02-13T13:00:00.000Z',
  '2022-02-13T13:49:16.000Z',
  '2022-02-13T14:00:00.000Z',
  '2022-03-08T13:00:00.000Z',
  '2022-04-13T13:00:00.000Z',
  '2022-05-13T13:00:00.000Z',
  '2022-06-13T13:00:00.000Z',
  '2022-07-13T13:00:00.000Z',
  '2022-08-13T13:00:00.000Z',
  '2022-09-13T13:00:00.000Z',
  '2022-10-13T13:00:00.000Z',
  '2022-11-13T14:00:00.000Z',
  '2022-12-13T14:00:00.000Z',
  '2023-01-13T14:00:00.000Z',
  '2023-02-13T14:00:00.000Z',
  '2023-03-13T13:00:00.000Z',
  '2023-04-13T13:00:00.000Z',
  '2023-05-13T13:00:00.000Z',
  '2023-06-13T13:00:00.000Z',
  '2023-07-13T13:00:00.000Z',
  '2023-08-13T13:00:00.000Z',
  '2023-09-13T13:00:00.000Z',
  '2023-10-13T13:00:00.000Z',
  '2023-11-13T14:00:00.000Z',
  '2023-12-13T14:00:00.000Z',
  '2024-01-13T14:00:00.000Z',
];

export const isWithin5Days = () => {
  const today = new Date();
  const futureDatesWithToday = rotaSchedules.map((date) => ({
    date,
    diff: Math.abs(new Date(date).getTime() - today.getTime()),
  }));
  const sortedFutureDatesWithToday = futureDatesWithToday.sort(
    (a, b) => a.diff - b.diff,
  );
  const nearestFutureDate = sortedFutureDatesWithToday[0].date;
  const diff = Math.abs(
    new Date(nearestFutureDate).getTime() - today.getTime(),
  );
  return {
    nearestFutureDate,
    isWithin5Days: diff < 5 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Before mapping `rotaSchedules`, you should first remove all the date that are in the past. To do so, you should write something like this

```js
const futureDatesWithToday = rotaSchedules
    .filter((date) => new Date(date).getTime() - today.getTime() > 0)
    .map((date) => ({
        date,
        diff: Math.abs(new Date(date).getTime() - today.getTime()),
     }));
```